# Angular <div> color change from script

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

im working on a angular 6. im changing the colors of a div tag from a script after a click function i need to change it back to transparent

Here is my View when i click the inheritance first line gets background color gets changed

[image]

after clicking inheritance when i click the Method Overriding the second lines get highlighted ***But i need to remove the background color from first line***

[image]

**Html code for side bar**

```
  <div *ngFor="let classes of classesObject ">
    <input id='{{classes}}' name='radio' type='radio'>
    <label (click)="clickClass(classes)" for='{{classes}}'>
      {{classes}}
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='swanky_wrapper__content'>
        <ul *ngFor="let conceptName of concepts">
          <li (click)="getConcepts(conceptName['conceptName'],[classes])">{{conceptName["conceptName"]}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
```

**Html code for line display**

```
 <div *ngFor="let lines of lineList; let i= index">
    <div id="line_{{i}}" class="code" >&nbsp;&nbsp;{{lines}}</div>
 </div>
```

**Typescript code for `getConcept` method**

```
  for (var no in this.relatedLineNo) {
    var lines = this.relatedLineNo[no] - 1;
    document.getElementById(`line_` + lines).style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById(`line_` + lines).style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById(`line_` + lines).style.cursor = "pointer";
    document.getElementById(`line_` + lines).setAttribute("tooltip", this.messageTip);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually looking up lines in a for loop with this:

`document.getElementById(`

Try a bit more Angular-ish approach:

`[ngClass]="{ hilite: i === relatedLineNo }"`

What happens is that inside your *ngFor loop Angular will evaluate current line index "i" with `relatedLineNo` and will "automatically" highlight the line.

**UPDATE**

If "relatedLineNo" is an array then you can use this:

```
[ngClass]="{ hilite: relatedLineNo.indexOf(i) !== -1 }"
```

Working and updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbtet7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).